# Maui - Responsive sizing (Fonts, control widths etc) based on screen size?

Tags: responsive, maui

[image: Example of different layouts / screen sizes]

Hi everyone,

I'm trying to create a 'Reactive' page inside .NET Maui.

I can't seem to find any help around reactive sizing. The example image shows a simple label with a 'longer' peice of text. In my Android Emulator (left) the text wraps, but in the larger iOS tablet (middle) the text doesn't.

If possible, i would like to be able to reduce the font size on the smaller screen (Right) so it fits nicely to the page, but obviously keep the original fontsize on larger devices

I come from a HTML background, so looking for the equivilent of css Media Queries?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean you want your App to have an adaptive UI layout based on different device screen sizes?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what i'm trying to do - I should have used the word 'responsive' not reactive. Basically something that adjust properties on elements, based on screensize

Comment: You can refer to [this thread](https://thenextloop.com/2021/01/03/adaptive-page-layouts-to-different-device-screen-sizes-for-xamarin-apps/) on the `responsive sizing`. I believe it'll shed on light for you.